# Display Div by Checkmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking for a function that receives two passed parameters that indicates which checkmark is triggered and which div should be displayed.

```
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" id="namchk" checked>Names</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" id="detchk" checked>Details</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" id="prichk" checked>Prices</label></td>
```

Each checkbox was given an Id and each div was given in Id ("names, details, prices")

```
   function showHide (chkmrk, divid)
```

How would I go about this function?

Comment: Where are the dvs to be displayed?

Comment: @user3383432, the function should show thos 2 elements and hide all the rest?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to write a function yourself before asking for help. When you do, provide what you've tried and explain how it's not working.

Comment: I would start off by adding a class to those checkboxes.  If one of those items in the class gets checked, assign a value to that of the id.  Since the id's match the div's, show/hide the divs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to have happen here.  I'm going to assume you're suggesting that depending on which checkbox is checked will display or hide a div.  This assumes you are using jquery

```
<script>
$(".test").click(function(event){
    var divName = event.target.id;
    if ($("#" + divName).prop('checked'))
    {
        $( "#" + divName + "_div").show();
    }
    else{
        $( "#" + divName + "_div").hide();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="namchk_div">namchk_div content</div>
<div id="detchk_div">detchk_div content</div>
<div id="prichk_div">prichk_div content</div>

<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="test" id="namchk" checked>Names</label></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="test" id="detchk" checked>Details</label></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="test" id="prichk" checked>Prices</label></td>
```